# Understanding Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

The Riesz representation theorem is very easy to understand. Further, every continuous linear functional $A[f]$ over the space $C([0, 1])$ of continuous functions in the interval $[0,1]$ can be represented in the form

$$A[f]=\int_0^1 fdg$$ (1)

where $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is a BV function on [0,1].

$g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is certainly not a Borel measure $\mu:\mathcal B(\mathbb R) \to\mathbb R$. But by the generalized form of representation theorem should the $g$ be a Borel measure?

Also when $f\in \mathcal H$ Hilbert space (L2), $\exists h(A[f]=f\cdot h)$ This is closely related to the previous equation (1). Borel measure seems not involved again.

But for a $L_1(\mathbb R)$ linear functional $T$ 
$$T(f)=\int_\mathbb R fd\mu$$

Where $\mu$ is Complex Borel measure. I think the only major difference between this and the equation (1) is the difference between [0,1] and $\mathbb R$, which should not be the source of "complex"?

Here what is difference between complex Borel measure and Borel measure? Why we need to use complex Borel measure for the $L_1(\mathbb R)$ case?

I totally get lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that in the first case, the functional is defined on the space of **continuous** functions (on a compact set) whereas in the second case the functional operates on the **integrable** functions.

For completeness' sake, I add that there also exists a version for continuous functions for which the integration is performed with respect to a measure. This result is much more general than the ones you mentioned, but in your case, the measure theoretic version and the one with a BV-function are essentially the same. The reason for this is that to each signed measure $\mu$ on an interval corresponds a function with bounded variation $g$ (and vice versa) such that the Riemann-Stieltjes-integral of a continuous function $f$ with respect to $g$ coincides with the Lebesgue-integral of $f$ with respect to $\mu$. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289754/borel-measures-and-bounded-variation) for some details.

As for the measure-theoretic versions, whether you have to use a real (i.e. signed) measure or a complex measure just depends on whether your functional is real- or complex-valued. This will most often coincide with whether your continuous/integrable functions are real- or complex-valued, since a linear functional is typically defined to be a linear mapping from a vector space into the underlying scalar field, which can only be $\mathbb{R}$ in the case of real-valued functions.

The Riesz theorem for Hilbert spaces is, although named the same, a completely different story. This theorem is about the interplay of continuous functionals and the inner product whereas the other theorems are concerned with the representation of functionals by means of an integral. The deeper similarity of all of them is that they offer characterisations of a dual space.

EDIT: As pointed out by Martin Argerami, the last paragraph is incorrect, I quote:

> Any Hilbert space can be represented as $H=L^2(X, \mu)$ for an appropriate measure space $X$, and so the Riesz Representation Theorem says that you can write a bounded functional $\phi$ by$$\phi(f)=\langle f,g\rangle = \int_X f\,\bar g\,d\mu.$$

Therefore, there is a much more immediate similarity between the Riesz theorems.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I guess this is the major difference between continuous function and integrable function is that the first one is of $\aleph_1$ and the second one is of $\aleph_2$ (assuming the continuum hypothesis)?  No wonder the first class could be represented by a real number valued measure of real numbers but the second can only be represented by a real number valued measure of all the subsets of real numbers.

Comment: @haemi: I wouldn't say that the theorem for Hilbert spaces is a "different story". Any Hilbert space can be represented as $H=L^2(X, \mu)$ for an appropriate measure space $X$, and so the Riesz Representation Theorem says that you can write a bounded functional $\phi$ by$$\phi(f)=\langle f,g\rangle = \int_X f\,\bar g\,d\mu.$$

Comment: @HighGPA I don't fully understand your reasoning (Why do the integrable functions have strictly larger cardinality than $\aleph_1$? And isn't the continuum hypothesis the assumption that there is no cardinal number strictly between $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$?), but if it is correct, it may provide an intuitive motivation. On the other hand, the measure-theoretic version for continuous functions and especially the duality between BV-functions and signed measures doesn't seem to fit into the picture...

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thank all of you. Is it possible that a functional defined on real functions can only be represented by integration over complex Borel measure (not a real Borel measure)?

Comment: @MartinArgerami You are right, my mistake. Thanks! I have updated my answer. In certain cases, the similarity is even more evident: if (using your notation) $g$ is not only $L^2$ but also $L^1$, we can define $\nu(A):=\int_A \bar{g}\,d\mu$ and obtain $$\phi(f)=\int f\,d\nu.$$ It would be interesting to find a characterisation of functionals whose Riesz representative is integrable...

Comment: @HighGPA it depends on whether your functional is real- or complex valued, but in most cases, a functional defined on a space of real valued functions will only attain real values as well. The reason for this is that e.g. the real valued continuous functions form a vector space over the real numbers (but not over the complex field), and a linear functional is typically defined to be a linear mapping from a vector space into the underlying scalar field.

Comment: @haemi Let $f(x)=x$, $Tf=x^{-1/2}f$,  $T$ is linear and $Tf(x)$ could be complex? ($x\in\mathbb R$)

Comment: @HighGPA Unfortunately, I don't quite understand: Do you specify the function $f$ or the functional $T$? And what do you mean by $Tf(x)$? $T$ must be a linear mapping from (for simplicity) $C[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{C}$...anyway, I think I know where you're going; do you want to define a complex valued functional on a space of real valued functions? If so, there are easier examples, too: set $Tf:=i\cdot f(0)$, $f\in C[0,1]$. Then $T$ is bounded (even a contraction) and a complex valued linear mapping. However, $T$ is not a **functional** on $C[0,1]$, since it doesn't map into its scalar field. [...]

Comment: @HighGPA [...] So to answer your question, it - as usual in mathematics - depends on the definition your are using. You are in no way hindered from defining a complex valued functional on real valued functions (which would require a complex measure in the Riesz theorem) but you very rarely work with them, since you want linear mappings into the scalar field - those make up the dual space which is an important object in functional analysis (hence the name!). Do you understand what I mean?